# Referencing variables between wpf forms

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Alright, so I have a form with textboxes and a button (Form 1), and that button opens a new form (Form 2) consisting of a textbox.

What I want to do is get the contents of one of the textboxes of the first form (like `TextboxForm1.Text`) and use that text in the second form, like `TextboxForm2.Text = {however to reference textbox 1 from form 1}.Text;`.

Is there an obvious way that I overlooked?

Thanks.

Edit: Tried both solutions and the both worked well, but making it public was much easier in the case of multiple textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx

```
<TextBox Name="TextboxForm1" x:FieldModifier="Public" />
```

Comment: I would only say make the entire control public if it is needed.

Comment: @GrantThomas I agree, I would actually recommend against setting control properties altogether, because of WPF's powerful data binding support (just pass the same DataContext to both forms)... but this *is* the most direct answer to the question "how to reference textbox 1".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use a property to expose the value of the desired textbox from the appropriate form. So, add something like the following to your window class:

```
public string TextBox1Text {
  get { return TextBox1.Text; }
}
```

And then access it from the instance, as you seem to know, like this:

```
AnotherTextBox.Text = instance.TextBox1Text;
```

As for using the access modifier for the control as per nmclean's answer (i.e. `FieldModifier="Public"`), I would only say make the entire control public if it is needed.